# How dynamically price change on product page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, price, custom-options

I am trying to update price of product on product page. So I am updating the span of price by getting `product price + my additional` price, but problem is when we use custom options.

Is there any `event or plugin` available using which I can add our price at final even after custom option.

Thank you,

Comment: using event you can set product final price without custom option price. Custom option price will add additionally.

Comment: @JaiminParikh so any other ways to do so

Comment: using "catalog_product_get_final_price" event you can get product final price.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK !
I found one solution to change the price on product page itself using Javascript:

```
require(["jquery","Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils"], function(jQuery,priceUtils) {
    var productPrice = parseFloat(jQuery('span.price-final_price > span[data-price-type="finalPrice"]').attr('data-price-amount'));
    var finalPrice=100;
    formatedPrice = priceUtils.formatPrice(parseInt(finalPrice));
    jQuery('span.price-final_price > span.price-wrapper > span.price').text(formatedPrice);
    var finalPrice=productPrice+(pricePerText*textObjects)+(pricePerImage*imageObjects);
    formatedPrice = priceUtils.formatPrice(parseInt(finalPrice));
    jQuery('span.price-final_price > span.price-wrapper > span.price').text(formatedPrice);
}); // Required
```

For more detail information :

https://www.codedecorator.com/blog/how-to-change-price-dynamically-on-product-page-in-magento2/

Comment: it is a good solution but i can't able to add my currency symbol before the formatted price could you suggest me?

Comment: How do I embed this javascript to code?