# How to change product price using drop down option in Magento 2?

Tags: price, jquery, magento2.3.0

I want to change product price when drop down option is change. Here drop down is dynamic means you can add **N** number of drop down and it's options from admin side.

(Note: **This is not a product custom option**)

I think i can get this using jQuery can anyone suggest me script.

Thanks In advance

[image]

Comment: you have try this? Ref: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/126850/68695